# Ger Toshav and Chukot hagoyim

Tags: halacha, noachide-laws, noahidism, hukot-hagoyim, ger-toshav

If somebody is a Ger Toshav (so an observant noahide who accepts and follows  the 7 mitzvot, and gets recognized as such by a Beit din), is there any obligation on them within Chukot Hagoyim (following the ways of the nations). This is of course otherwise non idolatry practices that are nonetheless prohibited for Jews due to being gentile origin customs, are they still allowed to practice all (non idolatry) gentile customs?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is yes; the radius of "smells kinda sorta like idolatry" is far wider for us than for non-Jews. Building/owning a statue of a person that won't actually be deified, for instance, is A-OK for them, not for us. (Rabbi Moshe Feinstein got that question about a mayor who wants the rabbi to contribute to the make-a-statue-of-President-Kennedy fund.) Put more simply above -- your question is if non-Jews can celebrate Halloween in its most Americanized, commercialized, tame version -- a bunch of six-year-olds dressed as superheroes and going door-to-door for candy.

Comment: I'd ask it more simply -- is Chukot HaGoyim included in the Sheva Mitzvot Bnai Noach?

Comment: @shalom Great thoughts but disagree on your second post; mitzva is a very specific term as are all of the terms thus there's a Halakha of X, which is its feet, a Kabbalah of X which is its arms, and so on. Mitva is the Amuda Emsaita, Center Pillar like from crown to spine. If I'm not mistaken there's a Ruach to it, and probably everything else the Torah has, Nevua, Chok, Hasidut, Tzaddikim. Maybe it has Na Nach too

Comment: Why would a Ger Toshav be prohibited from following the 'ways of the goyim'? He's a goy who's chosen to remain one.

Comment: @KirkBellard the very definition of chukat hagoyim is a non-Jewish custom that's *not* directly linked to idolatry (otherwise those things would be prohibited to Jews as Avodah Zarah rather than chukat hagoyim). So I ask again - why would there be a reason to prohibit a Ger Toshav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No a Ger Toshav bc he is Toshav he's dwelling he's not a Ger Sedeq of righteousness i.e.Yesod. The latter ought to avoid Chukot hagoyyim as other Yisrael do.

Edit: Just a guess that Chok relates to Tzedek - Yesod and therefore requires more protection.

References: Sifrei Breslev

Comment: Your answer is correct (and contains the same contnet as my comment) but you need to either cite a source or explain in your answer why there is no source available